# JAVASCRIPT log-in redirect with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication, local-storage

i am doing a project on javascript and can't figure out one thing and that is how to log-in and then re direct the user to a specific version of the website. Example, if you are not logged in you can't use an option on a shopping website to buy goods. But when logged in that option becomes available. My task is to do this all using local storage for the log-in. I can only use Javascript for this
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function store() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var pw = document.getElementById('pw');
    var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon')
    var email = document.getElementById('email')
    var adresa = document.getElementById('adresa')
    var drzava = document.getElementById('drzava')
    var mrod = document.getElementById('mrod')
    var zrod = document.getElementById('zrod') 

    localStorage.setItem('name', name.value);
    localStorage.setItem('pw', pw.value);
    localStorage.setItem('telefon', telefon.value);
    localStorage.setItem('email', email.value);
    localStorage.setItem('adresa', adresa.value);
    
}

function check() {

    var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var storedPw = localStorage.getItem('pw');

    var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
    var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw');

    if(userName.value == storedName && userPw.value == storedPw) {
        alert('You are loged in.');
    }else {
        alert('ERROR.');
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    font:1em "Open sans", sans-serif;
}
 
.content {
    padding:30px;
}
 
.nav-main{
    background-color:#222;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    height: 70px;
}
 
.nav-main .logo {
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    padding:15px 30px;
    font-size:2.4em;
    line-height:40px;
}
 
.nav-main > ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
 float: left;
}
.nav-item {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:15px 20px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height:40px;
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;

}

.nav-item:hover {
 background-color:#444
}

.nav-content {
 position:absolute;
 top: 70px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color:#222;
 max-height:0;
}

.nav-content a {
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-content a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}

.nav-sub {
 padding:20px;
}

.nav-sub ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type:none;
}

.nav-sub ul li a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px 0;

}

.nav-item:focus {
 background-color:#444;
}

.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
 max-height:400px;
 -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s ease-in;
 -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s ease-in;
 transition:max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
h1 {
margin-left: 70px;
}
form li {
list-style: none;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

form ul li label{
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 100px;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 10px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}

form ul li input, select, span {
float: left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form textarea {
float: left;
width: 350px;
height: 150px;
}

[id="rgstr_btn"] {
margin: none;
margin: 230px -120px;
font-size:12px
}

[id="login_btn"] {
margin: none;
margin: 58px -100px;
font-size:12px
}
p {
margin-left: 70px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registruj se</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo"><b>Oglasi</b></div>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="Pocetna.html" class="nav-item">Pocetna</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Kupovina.html" class="nav-item">Kupovina</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Prodaja.html" class="nav-item">Prodaja</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Kategorije</a>
    <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="nav-sub">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="IPhone.html">IPhone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sony</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Registruj_se.html" class="nav-item">Registruj se</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Uloguj_se.html" class="nav-item">Uloguj se</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Moj_profil.html" class="nav-item">Moj profil</a>
    </li> 
    </ul>
        
    </nav>
     
 <form id="login-form">
         <ul>
            <li><label for="Enter Username">Korisnicki ID:</label></li> 
            <li><input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value=""/></li>
            <li><label for="Enter Password">Sifra:</label></li>
            <li><input id="userPw" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value=""/></li>
            <li><button id="login_btn" type="button" value="Login" onClick="check()"/>Login</button></li>
        </ul>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript location object to send the user to another page when there login is no longer valid. location.assign("http://homepage/home.com");